# How to pass boolean values between PHP, HTML forms, and Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, boolean

I have a PHP program that uses HTML forms and uses JavaScript for validation.  There's a hidden field in the HTML form containing a boolean value that gets set by PHP, validated on submission by JavaScript, and passed to another PHP page.

When I tried to use PHP booleans to set the value of the HTML field, JavaScript evaluated it as blank, so I used ones and zeros and compared them numerically instead, and now it works fine.

My question is: what is best practice in this scenario?  How do I get JavaScript to read a true/false value in my PHP-driven HTML hidden field without using ones and zeros?  Or is that just a bad idea altogether?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The good news is that PHP and JavaScript have a similar idea about what values are true and false.

- An empty string will be false on both sides. A string with something in it (except `0` in PHP) will be true on both sides.
- The number `0` will be false on both sides. All other numbers will be true on both sides.

Since the values of a form will always be strings, as Quentin pointed out in his answer, a good practice might be to use an empty string as false value and something else (e.g. `'true'`) as true value. But I think your way of using `0` and `1` and testing the numerical values is the safest approach because it isn't misleading. (When someone sees `'true'` they might think `'false'` would also be usable for a false value.

Answer (score 7):

The value of a form control will *always* be a string.

If you want a boolean, then you have to encode it *somehow* and then parse it *somehow*.

Using a 0 or 1 is a perfectly good approach. You could also use `true` and `false` (which you could generate using `json_encode` on the PHP side) and run the value through `JSON.parse`. There are numerous other options along similar lines.

Comment: can you write how can we encode strings to boolean in html and then pass the data to php script?

Comment: @WijaySharma — I did. Read the last paragraph of the answer.